# FirebaseJobDispatcher - schedule calendar events

Tags: android, calendar, job-scheduling, firebase-job-dispatcher

I need to implement calendar notifications similar to Google Calendar notifications. Notifications should work offline, so FCM is not an option.

I tried to use Firebase Job Scheduler, my schedule is created like this:

```
FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
```

Then schedule job:

```
Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
    .setService(MyJobService.class)
    .setTag("my-unique-tag")        
    .build();

dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

My problem is that above code only schedules single job (it probably also could be sheduled as periodic job). I need to schedule notifications for all events from my internal app calendar, for each date.

I think creating multiple jobs is not a good idea (since, afaik there is some limit for jobs count per app).
Can you show me the best solution to do what I want?

Comment: you can also do like this: start first service and when it is finished start another within that process.

Comment: one more thing are you using async task for services and what about calender, is it your's or using google's ?

Comment: Why don't go for [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) ?

Comment: There are some limitations for AlarmManager on Oreo. I think AlarmManager is deprecated now

Comment: @Umair my own calendar. I don't want application to hold wakelock and battery drain. But job should be triggered even when app is not running

Comment: Deprecated? Who said that? Kindly go through this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html)

Comment: @user1209216 what I did was I called multiple services like i told you even when my mobile screen was off it ran and all worked fine. (But I am using firebase so not sure how it will work on locally).

Comment: As far as I understand, your solution won't work offline on Oreo. You will get exception if you try to start another backround service in background, it's not allowed